# validation error message not hide after selection of checkbox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my communication page I have five checkboxes and If user not check any of the checkboxes then I am showing validation error message on the label Like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#communication_form").submit(function ( event ) {
      var phone_value = $("#cb_Phone").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
      var email_value = $("#cb_Email").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
      var skype_value = $("#cb_Skype").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
      var website_value = $("#cb_Website").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
      var twitter_value = $("#cb_Twitter").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;
      var hasError = false;

      if(phone_value == 0 && email_value == 0 && skype_value == 0 && website_value == 0 && twitter_value == 0)
      {             
         var message = $("#errormessage").html("Please Select");//alert("Hassan");
         message.show();
         hasError = true;
      } 
      else
      {
         hasError = false;
      }
      if(hasError)
      {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
   });
</script>
```

And its working fine but when I check any checkbox of the 5 checkboxes validation error message not remove and below is the label where I am showing validation error message:

```
<table align="center" width="100%">
      <tr>
         <td>

         </td>
         <td></td>
         <td>
            <label for="validation_all" id="errormessage" visible="false" style="font-size:60%; color:red;"></label>
         </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

waiting for reply.
Thanks.

Comment: I have a same case on thispage for email, If I am enter invalid email in the textbox then it show error message "Invalid email" and its working fine but when I enter "valid email" error message not going

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not clear & hide the message div in else part so use below code

Try this

```
 else
  {
     hasError = false;
     $("#errormessage").empty().hide(); // This line will clear the div and hide
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

update `visible` attribute of `errormessage` to `false` on click on checkbox

```
$("#cb_Phone,#cb_Email,#cb_Skype,#cb_Website,#cb_Twitter").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
       $("#errormessage").attr('visible','false');
    }
});
```

This will remove the error message as soon as user selects any of the checkbox.

Also you can make your code more clean and simple

```
$("#communication_form").submit(function ( event ) {
   // Length 0 means no checkbox is selected
   if($("#cb_Phone,#cb_Email,#cb_Skype,#cb_Website,#cb_Twitter:checked").length = 0){
      var message = $("#errormessage").html("Please Select");//alert("Hassan");
      message.show();
      event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
if(phone_value == 0 && email_value == 0 && skype_value == 0 && website_value == 0 && twitter_value == 0)
      {             
         var message = $("#errormessage").html("Please Select");//alert("Hassan");
         message.show();
         hasError = true;
      } 
      else
      {
        $("#errormessage").html(''); 
// OR $("#errormessage").hide();
         hasError = false;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would declare the message outside the if-clause and then set message to hide in else, ie:

```
var message = $("#errormessage").html("Please Select");//alert("Hassan");

    if(phone_value == 0 && email_value == 0 && skype_value == 0 && website_value == 0 && twitter_value == 0)
    {             
        message.show();
        hasError = true;
    }
    else
    {
        hasError = false;
        message.empty().hide();
    }
```